# How can you save a TensorSliceDataset into a path?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to save a TensorSliceDataset as a file so that I can transfer it between computers, but simply using `.save(filepath)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of saving the TensorSliceDataset, I saved the data I converted into the TensorSliceDataset instead.